# javascript, three.js - how to tween the camera's FOV

Tags: javascript, webgl, three.js

I'm trying to follow this tutorial:

http://learningthreejs.com/blog/2011/08/17/tweenjs-for-smooth-animation/

to tween a camera's field of view in three.js, but the value doesn't seem to be updating. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? This is my code:

```
    var fov = 70;
    var zoomFov = 100;

    function onDocumentMouseUp( event ) {
        castRay(); 
    }

    function castRay(){
        var vector = new THREE.Vector3( ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1, - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1, 0.5 );
        projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );
        var ray = new THREE.Ray( camera.position, vector.subSelf( camera.position ).normalize() );
        var intersects = ray.intersectObjects( objects );
        if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
            var camObj = intersects[0].object;
            camTween = new TWEEN.Tween( fov ).to( zoomFov,500 ).easing( camEase );
            camTween.start();
            camTween.onUpdate(function(){
                updateCam(fov);
            });
        }
    }

    function updateCam(fov){
       console.log(fov); //MH - outputs 70 every time
    }

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    render();
    TWEEN.update();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this with the following code. Seems that the tween class needs a property of an object in order to update correctly(?)

```
var fov = 70, zoomFov = 10, currentFov, camTween;

function castRay(){
    var vector = new THREE.Vector3( ( event.clientX / window.innerWidth ) * 2 - 1, - ( event.clientY / window.innerHeight ) * 2 + 1, 0.5 );
    projector.unprojectVector( vector, camera );
    var ray = new THREE.Ray( camera.position, vector.subSelf( camera.position ).normalize() );
    var intersects = ray.intersectObjects( objects );
    if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
        setupTween();
    }
}

function setupTween(){
    var update = function(){=
        camera.projectionMatrix.makePerspective( currentFov.fov, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 1100 );
        render();
    }

    currentFov = { fov: 70};
    TWEEN.removeAll();
    camTween = new TWEEN.Tween( currentFov ).to( {fov: zoomFov},500 ).easing( camEase ).onUpdate(update);
    camTween.start();
}

function animate() {

    requestAnimationFrame( animate );
    render();
    TWEEN.update();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're not calling `camTween.update()` ever.  If you don't have a render loop somewhere in your code, something like the following may be able to fix it:

```
setInterval(function(){ 
    camTween.update(); 
}, 50);
```

Otherwise I'd put a call to `camTween.update()` in your render loop.